# Картинка в ActionBar

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток. Нужно сделать название приложения в `ActionBar` не текстом, а красивой картинкой. Можно ли в `ActionBar` отобразить картинку вместо текста?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В разметке:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_default_height"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="top">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

В Activity

```
private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    // Если хотите изменить или назначить какое-нибудь действие
    logo = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_logo);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Activity также должна наследовать AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

```
Drawable d=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background_image_name);  
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

Comment: Крашится( и перечеркивает `.getDrawable`
http://i.stack.imgur.com/82MwY.png